# Display Json on Gridview inside A Gridview

Tags: c#, json, text, gridview, uwp

I have a Json, like the image below:

[image: json]

I want to display "majors" into a gridview inside a gridview

XAML:

```
<GridView x:Name="asesmenGridView">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="asesmenGrid"> 
                <TextBlock  
                    x:Name="judulT"
                    Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                <GridView
                    x:Name="majorGridView"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.majordatasource, ElementName=asesmenGridView}">
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MajorClass">
                                <Grid>
                                                                        <TextBlock
                                                                            x:Name="kelasT"
                                                                            Text="{x:Bind Major}"  />
                                                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                                                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                                </GridView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Code:

```
    public MainPage()
                {
                    this.InitializeComponent();
                this.DataContext = this;
                }
        public List<MajorClass> majordatasource { get; set; } = new List<MajorClass>();    
        string urlPath = "https://.../choose-exam/2";
                                    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
                                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization",
                                        string.Format("Bearer {0}", tkn));
                                    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlPath);
             string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                    try
                                    {
                                        JsonArray jsonArray = JsonArray.Parse(jsonText);
                                        foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
                                        {
                                            string title = groupObject["title"].GetString();
             JsonArray majorArray = groupObject["majors"].GetArray();
                                            MajorClass majorC = new MajorClass();
                                            foreach (JsonValue majorValue in majorArray)
                                            {
                                                JsonObject majorObject = majorValue.GetObject();
                                                double majorID = majorObject["major_id"].GetNumber();
                                                string major = majorObject["major"].GetString();
            
                                                majorC.MajorID = (int)majorID;
                                                majorC.Major = major + ",";
                                                majordatasource.Add(majorC);
                                            }
Ujian ujian = new Ujian();
                                    ujian.Title = title;
             ujiandatasource.Add(ujian);
            }
            asesmenGridView.ItemsSource = ujiandatasource;
```

Ujian Class:

```
public class Ujian
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<MajorClass> majordatasource { get; set; }

        public Ujian()
        {
            Title = string.Empty;
            majordatasource = new ObservableCollection<MajorClass>();
        }

        public Ujian(string title)
        {
            Title = title;
        }
    }

    public class MajorClass
    {
        public int MajorID { get; set; }
        public string Major { get; set; }
    }
}
```

From the code above, I didn't manage to display it on the gridview in a gridview (the data that is retrieved is only the last data and is displayed repeatedly, as shown below).

[image: gridview]

How to handle it?

Comment: Does the following work, any updates for this thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your design, you need nest list data structure, and `majorGridView` could access `majordatasource` property of Ujian directly. Please pass majordatasource to   `ujian.majordatasource`, but not access separate majordatasource property where in the page class.

**For example**

```
Ujian ujian = new Ujian();
ujian.Title = title;
ujian.majordatasource = majordatasource；
ujiandatasource.Add(ujian)
```

**Xaml**

```
<GridView
 x:Name="majorGridView"
 ItemsSource="{Binding majordatasource}">
```

**Update**

```
try
{
    JsonArray jsonArray = JsonArray.Parse(jsonText);
    foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
    {
        var groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
        string title = groupObject["title"].GetString();
        JsonArray majorArray = groupObject["majors"].GetArray();
        var majordatasource = new ObservableCollection<MajorClass>();
       
        foreach (JsonValue majorValue in majorArray)
        {
            MajorClass majorC = new MajorClass();
            JsonObject majorObject = majorValue.GetObject();
            double majorID = majorObject["major_id"].GetNumber();
            string major = majorObject["major"].GetString();

            majorC.MajorID = (int)majorID;
            majorC.Major = major + ",";
            majordatasource.Add(majorC);
        }


        Ujian ujian = new Ujian();
        ujian.majordatasource = majordatasource;
        ujian.Title = title;
        ujiandatasource.Add(ujian);
    }
}
catch
{

}
```

Comment: On the `ujian.majordatasource = majordatasource；`. had an error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<KipinSchool_Win10.PTO.MajorClass>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<KipinSchool_Win10.PTO.MajorClass>'`

Comment: update this line  `public List<MajorClass> majordatasource { get; set; } = new List<MajorClass>(); ` to `public ObservableCollection<MajorClass> majordatasource { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MajorClass>();`

Comment: I've changed it like your code above, but still having the same problem, that is only the last data is successfully retrieved and displayed repeatedly.

Comment: Have you updated xaml code like above ?

Comment: Yes, I have changed it from `ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.majordatasource, ElementName=asesmenGridView}"` to `ItemsSource="{Binding majordatasource}"`

Comment: I have updated the code, please refer it. move `MajorClass majorC = new MajorClass()` into foreach block.